# #inner container to fill the remaining browser height

Tags: css

Site on staging for reference: [salto.wpengine.com/menu](http://salto.wpengine.com/menu)

I have a site that uses a **sticky footer** (forces the footer to the bottom of the browser window). There is a background image container within `#inner` that adds a translucent **white background** and we would like `#inner` to fill the remaining height (if there is any) on larger monitors and meet with the sticky footer, so that that column always appears to be touching the footer.

I cannot seem to work my way through a solution.  Has anyone had any luck with something like this?

Comment: I always use this solution for a sticky footer http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ and here's an example with BG color all the way until footer: http://jsfiddle.net/J2rcf/

Comment: your code demo in jsfiddle.net will be useful